# Copy only files from specific named folders in directory structure

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste, folder-redirection, file-filter

Not entirely sure how to word this right in the title so please edit if you know a better description.

I am running Windows 10 and I have a large directory, filled with over 100 other directories that have similar structures to each other, I want to copy and preserve all child directory names and only a specific directoy name with its contents while ignoring the rest of the folders and files.

For example:

```
Dir
    Child
         Textures
         Scripts
         Meshes
         Somefile.esp
     Child2
         Textures
         Meshes
         Readme.txt
```

This is about 150 different folders and most of them contain a texture folder.

What I would like to do is copy the entire directory structure for all the child directory's, but only keeping their Texture folders with them in the copy.

This seems it would be the easiest way to achieve this, but I suppose it would work out as well if I just excluded certain folder names (like meshes, scripts) and filetypes (like txt, esp). But that may leave a few missed in the exclusion.

Is there a third party tool that can do this or do this via the exclusion method? 
A batch or some other script would be just fine too. Wouldn't even mind installing cygwin or win-bash to implement a Linux command pipe to achieve this as well.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It can be done by a script file for sure. However, we are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "Is there a third party tool that can do this?" Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Only asked here because I was lead here by this question which is quite similar.  http://superuser.com/questions/414930/copy-files-of-certain-type-in-directory-and-subdirectories-preserving-structure?newreg=96c9cdc445ba4820a5312a68848300e1
They did not state anything they tried and were provided with many responses. If my question is no longer accepted here, fine delete it.

Comment: That is an old question (2012) and what is deemed as acceptable (by the community) has changed. We now expect people to make some effort (research and have a go) when asking for a script. And as I said in a previous comment you could try softwarerecs.stackexchange.com for a ready made program request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it can be done with powershell. You might have a look at this, and see if it'll work for what you're trying.

```
Copy-Item -path "Source_Folder" -Recurse -Include "Textures" -Destination "Destination_Folder" -Container
```

The "-Container" switch should re-create the correct structure, but I can't promise that this will only copy the "Textures" folders correctly for you.

Comment: I definitely think this may do it using either include and adjusting or filter. Currently its not doing anything I think because it isn't going down into the child directories to look for texture folder. I figured recurse should fix that but for some reason its not doing anything. May be my mistake though. Definitely going to look into this more thanks.